# Self-referencing variable *** what am I missing?

Tags: pine-script

Please find the code for calculating the supertrend indicator

```
study("VJ2 Supertrend V1.0 - Buy or Sell Signal", overlay = true)

Factor=input(3.0, minval=1,maxval = 140)
Pd=input(14, minval=1,maxval = 140)

Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))

TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red
plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend")
```

Here, the "TrendUp" variable is calculated based, among others, on its own value in the preceding bar "TrendUp[1]".

Therefore, it is a recursive calculation.

What I do not understand is how the first value of the variable "TrendUp" is calculated. For example:

1. for bar number 1 the value of "TrendUp" cannot be calculated because the value of "TrendVar" for the preceding bar does not exist
2. for bar number 2  the value of "TrendUp" cannot be calculated because the value of "TrendVar" for the bar bar number 1 does not exist
3. and so on...

There must be something that I am missing, since the SuperTrend indicator works correctly.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

The first value actually is set up as `na`
If you try the code:

```
study("my script")
m = m[1]
plot(m)
```

Then you'll see `n/a`.
To overcome this you need to write a code with selfreferencing using the function `nz()` (or using extra condition as did you in your snippet):

```
study("my script")
m = nz(m[1])
// m = nz(m[1], 4)  // or alternatively with installing a value if na
plot(m)
```

NOTE: you're using an obsolete version of pine (without any explicit version), in the current version of pine (version=3) it doesn't work - you need to setup a value before reference to the previous value:

```
//@version=3
study("my script")
m = 0
m := nz(m[1])
plot(m)
```